# jquery convert array to string html

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

as the title stated. how do i do that? i read in some forum to use **stringify?** and how do i use it?

PHP:

```
$notes = $db->query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id_user = '$id_user'");
$output = array();
while($note = $notes->fetch_assoc()) {
  $noting = '<span class="block_note">'.$note['note'].'</span>';
  array_push($output, $noting);
}
$data['ok'] = true;
$data['message'] = $output;
echo json_encode($data);
```

jQuery:

```
$.get("include/get_details.php?id_user=1",function(data){
  if (data.ok){
     $.each(data, function(key,id){
        $("#notes").append(data.message);
     })

  }
}, "json");
```

Output:

```
{
"ok":true,
"message":[
  "<span class=\"block_note\">note1<\/span>",
  "<span class=\"block_note\">note2<\/span>",
  "<span class=\"block_note\">note3<\/span>"
]
}
```

Comment: I don't get this question. By using json_encode you (in a way) convert a array to a string (or object). How to you want to use this? Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.get("include/get_details.php?id_user=1",function(data){
  if (data.ok){
     $.each(data.message, function(key,value){
        $("#notes").append(value);
     })

  }
}, "json");
```

Comment: thanks.. i tried ur way before for some reason it didnt work.. and its working fine. weird.. lol.. thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

[array.join(separator)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

In you case:

```
message = data.message;
html = message.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to do this would be to use the jQuery .toArray() function, and then javascript join().

Like this:

```
var myArray = $(".block_note").toArray();
myArray.join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.message` is a JavaScript [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), so you can just use the [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method:

```
...
if (data.ok){
    $("#notes").append(data.message.join(""));
}
...
```

The `Array` object also provides various [iteration methonds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) which you should find useful.

PS: you can also write your PHP code like this:

```
$data = array();
$data['message'] = array();
while($note = $notes->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data['message'][] = '<span class="block_note">' . $note['note'] . '</span>';
}
$data['ok'] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("include/get_details.php?id_user=1",function(data){
  if (data.ok){
     $.each(data.message, function(key,id){
     $("#notes").append(id);
    });
  }
}, "json");
```

Check out the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_s/58cLY/